# How to prevent Visual Studio 2010 SP1 from generating a bin folder during build?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, configuration

I configured a project, right-click Properties, Compile tab, Build output path to a relative folder called Assemblies. I unchecked the option Generate XML documentation file. And still, a Bin folder is generated on the same level with my Assemblies folder, and the DLLs are generated in both places (Assemblies and Bin).

How can I prevent the Bin folder from being created and populated?

Comment: Asked 7 years too late, that always makes it hard to verify.  Did you also change the setting for the Release build?  Why are assemblies generated in bin when the normal build path is bin\Debug and bin\Release?  What were you planning on doing to keep these different configurations separate?  Why is this hack needed?

Comment: This is an old application, the original developers are no longer available. The idea is to have all DLLs in a single location, to be easy to set dependencies/references (Reference Paths). There are over 30 projects in the solution.

Comment: Hmya, it already works that way.  MSBuild automatically copies dependencies, it looks at the assembly manifest, the exact equivalent of  what Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies does.  Maybe you ought to spend some more time on the detailed build trace to see what is really going on.  Copy/paste the relevant entry into your question.